# polymer only works when launched with chrome dev editor

Tags: polymer, chrome-dev-editor

It's more of a question of why rather than please fix this. Polymer elements are made for websites, not just chrome apps, right? So why when I open the html file with chrome does it not work but when I run it with chrome dev editor and it opens with chrome does it work? I'd like to build a website using polymer elements, and I'm more than happy to use chrome dev editor, I just wanna know how it'll work if I try to publish.

Comment: This question doesn't provide any actionable information. Polymer is known to work in all modern browsers (and some not so modern ones too).

Comment: I'm not asking about the browsers I'm asking how I can get it to work without chrome dev editor

Comment: Please provide the information that allows to reproduce your issue, then others can investigate.

Comment: when I open the html file with chrome instead of chrome dev editor -> chrome, I get this:

Imported resource from origin 'file://' has been blocked from loading by Cross-Origin Resource Sharing policy: Invalid response. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.

Comment: This means you need a HTTP server. Chrome prevents stuff when loaded from `file:///...`. As you see: The first concrete information you provided led to a concrete suggestion towards a solution (don't actually know if this will finally solve your problem but should be a start).

Answer (score 1):

In order to run a website or webpage that is build with Polymer you will need a server.

Chrome Dev Editor provides a local server when we try to run our code, thus it works from Chrome Dev Editor. However when you open the html file with chrome there is no server set up.

When you run using Chrome Dev Editor you can see in address bar something like this `http://127.0.0.1:31999/test/test.html`

However when you try opening the html file in chrome you can see in address bar something like this `file:///D:/Users/test/test.html`

If you don't want Chrome Dev Editor to run your code then you can have local server set up using NodeJS etc. Or use editors like Brackets - it will set up a local server and run your webpage in browser.